# Xcode error: Auto property synthesis is synthesizing property not explicitly synthesized

Tags: ios, xcode

Have added two properties in a  .h file:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic, readonly) float weightInLbs;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSDate *date;
```

They generate this Xcode error: Auto property synthesis is synthesizing property not explicitly synthesized

Am running Xcode 5.1 and am targeting iOS 7.1.

What does this mean, and what do I need to do about it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to change 'implicit synthesized properties' flag in Project Build Settings

Comment: The only flag I see with that name is under "Apple LLVM 6.0 - Warnings - Objective C".  Silencing the warning does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have implemented a Getter Method?
Like:

```
-(float)weightInLbs
```

If you do so, your properties do not get synthesized automatically anymore (if you have readwrite properties it's the same if you implement both, a getter and a setter).
To fix this you only need to add `@synthesize weightInLbs;`in your implementation file (.m).